# Automatic refresh using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell the jQuery code for automatic refreshing of a page?

---

i am using something like this -

```
    jQuery(".form_" + form_count).html("<div id='message'></div>")
    jQuery('#message').html("<center><h2><br><br>Thank You Your form has been submitted.</h2></center>")
window.setTimeout(function() {
    history.go(-1);
}, 1950);
```

Now what i want is that after the browser has moved one page back to history that page should be refreshed . I tried using the above answers but no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used...

```
window.location = window.location
```

But it [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099276/automatic-refresh-using-jquery/3099290#3099290) that...

```
window.location.reload();
```

...exists, and it also more semantically correct. Pass an argument as `true` if you'd like to trigger a *hard* reload.

Of course, this is **not** jQuery. Remember jQuery is a JavaScript framework.

Comment: Why did you complete your answer with info from an answer for this same question. This does not seem fair to me, you know. Especially that you had no idea about feature.

Comment: @Ionut I voted the answer up and decided to edit it in just to be more *complete* with my own answer. He still has the most upvotes. I thought by including a link to my source and voting him up, I had *paid my dues* to the help he gave me.

Answer (score 6):

```
window.location.reload()
```

No jQuery needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.reload()` is equivalent to pressing the reload button in your browser.
`window.location = window.location` is equivalent to pressing enter in the address bar.

When you call `window.location.reload()`, all other resources are also revalidated. This means the cache fresness for all stylesheets, scripts and images is checked by performing extra HTTP-requests. At least in Firefox this behavior exists, I don't know how other browsers behave.